# Node Promise return object with value of resolved promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, fs

I have some code below that will return all files in a directory with certain keys and values. One of those keys I want to be isDirectory with a boolean value.

The code below works just fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to remove the Promise.all/iterating over promises and instead pushing the resolved value of the `stat.isDirectory()` to my files objects directly in my map.

**My solution I tried but failed:**

I tried something like this:

```
isDirectory: fs.statAsync(path).then((stat) => stat.isDirectory())
```

And then do a Promise.all on all the `isDirectory` keys

**Working Code:**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird'),
    os = require('os'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs')),
    desktopPath = `${os.homedir()}/Desktop`;

let files = [];

return fs.readdirAsync(desktopPath)
    .then((filesName) => files = _.map(filesName, (fileName) => ({
        path: `${desktopPath}/${fileName}`,
        name: fileName,
        ext: _.last(fileName.split('.'))
    })))
    .then(() => Promise.all(_.map(files, (file) => fs.statAsync(file.path))))
    .then((stats) => _.forEach(stats, (stat, idx) => {
        files[idx].isDirectory = stat.isDirectory();
    }))
    .then(() => {
        console.log(files);
    })
```

Is there anyway to remove the Promise.all and _.forEach part at the end? And instead do those actions in my map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest Node - you can `async/await`, put `async` before your function definition and do:

```
const fileNames = await fs.readdirAsync(desktopPath);
const files = await Promise.map(fileNames, fileName => Promise.props({
  path: `${desktopPath}/${fileName}`,
  name: fileName,
  ext: fileName.split('.').pop(),
  isDirectory: fs.statAsync(`${desktopPath}/${fileName}`);
})));
console.log(files);
return files;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the `Promise.all` entirely, because you want to wait for all files to finish before you use the final result. But you can do it all in one `.then()` call.

Because `map` is synchronous, it won't wait for the `fs.statAsync` to finish. But you can create an array of promises of `fs.statAsync` that resolve with the final files object and the simply wait for all of them to complete by using `Promise.all`.

A verbose version with some comments for clarification:

```
fs.readdirAsync(desktopPath)
  .then(fileNames => {
    // Array of promises for fs.statAsync
    const statPromises = fileNames.map(fileName => {
      const path = `${desktopPath}/${fileName}`;
      // Return the final file objects in the promise
      return fs.statAsync(path).then(stat => ({
        path,
        name: fileName,
        ext: _.last(fileName.split(".")),
        isDirectory: stat.isDirectory()
      }));
    });
    // Promise.all to wait for all files to finish
    return Promise.all(statPromises);
  })
  .then(finalFiles => console.log(finalFiles));
```

And the compact version:

```
fs.readdirAsync(desktopPath)
  .then(fileNames => Promise.all(
    fileNames.map(fileName =>
      fs.statAsync(`${desktopPath}/${fileName}`).then(stat => ({
        path: `${desktopPath}/${fileName}`,
        name: fileName,
        ext: _.last(fileName.split(".")),
        isDirectory: stat.isDirectory()
      })))
  ))
  .then(finalFiles => console.log(finalFiles));
```